# google adsense ad not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, adsense

Here my code for the ad, I can't get the ad to appear on my website.
I've tried tons of different ideas, but i cant seem to figure it out.
Any advice would be awesome.
Thank you guys so much!

```
   <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Random Dota Hero</title>
     </head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="randomdotacss.css" media="screen" />
     <body background="pa.jpeg"> 
     <body>
     <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
     <!-- Leaderboard Ad -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx"
    data-ad-slot="xxx"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Any update on your issue? I'm having a similar issue - only one of my ads is showing, I've waited more than 24 hours for others to display, but still nothing...

Comment: any luck dude?
did you ever find any solution, i am facing the same problem

Comment: its even wierder for me ,its showing on top of the page but not on bottom ,any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I would open the console on Google Chrome and see if you see any error messages

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, none there.

Comment: Is the account new? I seem to recall Adsense serving blank ads for my account until they approved the account a few hours later